# How to Configure Apache mod_proxy to proxy Glassfish 4.1 on Fedora 21?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy, glassfish, ajp

i have glassfish 4.1 running and checked the JK-Listener option on http-listener-2:

[image: JK Listener checked]

also i already installed apache (*sudo yum install httpd*) and created the following file on **/etc/httpd/conf.d**:

> ## /etc/httpd/conf.d/ajp.conf
>
> ProxyPass /painel ajp://localhost:8181/painel
>
> ProxyPassReverse /painel ajp://localhost:8181/painel

But all that i got trying to use the ajp protocol was the 503 http error.

What i am missing?

if i change the protocol from ajp to http and port to 8080, it works. But the idea was to use the ajp.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

You've likely run into an issue with SELinux.

By default the web server can only make outbound connections to a limited range of ports:

```
# semanage port -l | grep http
http_cache_port_t              tcp      8080, 8118, 8123, 10001-10010
http_cache_port_t              udp      3130
http_port_t                    tcp      80, 81, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 9000
pegasus_http_port_t            tcp      5988
pegasus_https_port_t           tcp      5989
```

Port 8181 isn't in that list.

So you have two options. You can either:

1. Add your desired port to the allowed ports list:

   ```
   # semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 8181
   ```
2. Run Glassfish on one of the existing allowed ports.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old post but I run into the same problem. My problem was the selinux and after I run the following:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

everything works fine!